# Elasticsearch: range query count of date range smaller than

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I'm storing a room object like this:

```
{
    "availability": 3,
    "bookings": [
        {
            "booking_interval": {
                "lt": "2024-05-16",
                "gte": "2024-05-09"
            },
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "booking_interval": {
                "lt": "2024-06-10",
                "gte": "2024-06-01"
            },
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "booking_interval": {
                "lt": "2024-06-12",
                "gte": "2024-06-02"
            },
            "quantity": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to search for a date interval and if the sum of quantity for the matches is smaller than availability, than the room type (i.e. double room) is available.

Something like this:

```
{
    "nested": {
        "path": "bookings",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "bookings.booking_interval": {
                                "gte": "2024-06-04",
                                "lt": "2024-06-06"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This only matches for the interval. This shouldn't return availability as for that interval that hotel has 3 double rooms and there are 2 bookings of 1 and 2 rooms already.

## Update

To clarify, there are 3 double rooms in the hotel.

Someone booked 2 for "2024-06-12" - "2024-06-02", and someone else booked one for "2024-06-10" - "2024-06-01"
This means that 2+1 !< 3 ( which is the availability) so there are no results.

For the interval "2024-05-16" - "2024-05-09" is fine because there is only 1 booking, 2 double rooms still available.

Answer (score 0):

Your request/needs is not clear, please elaborate more and check the following maybe it can help.

If you set `sum_quantity` lower than or equal to three it will return 0 result because max `quantity` is `2` in the data.

```
PUT /rooms
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "availability": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "bookings": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "booking_interval": {
            "type": "date_range"
          },
          "quantity": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
POST /rooms/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"availability": 3,"bookings":[{"booking_interval":{"lt":"2024-05-16","gte":"2024-05-09"},"quantity":1},{"booking_interval":{"lt":"2024-06-10","gte":"2024-06-01"},"quantity":1},{"booking_inter    val":{"lt":"2024-06-12","gte":"2024-06-02"},"quantity":2}]}
```

---

```
GET /rooms/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "bookings",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "bookings.booking_interval": {
                        "gte": "2024-06-04",
                        "lt": "2024-06-06"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['availability'].value > params.sum_quantity",
            "params": {
              "sum_quantity": 2
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```